# How to format exogenous variables when forecasting multiple related time series using n-hits or n-beats neural network forecasting models

Tags: time-series, neural-networks

**Motivation**:
I would like to forecast Canadian Inflation Index using N-HITS or N-BEATS model (I have considered both pytorch forecasting package and neuralforecast python packages).

I hope to use exogenous variables such as bank rate, employment rate, labor participation in forecast, and I also want to use the different components of inflation price index (all items, food, goods, services, clothing, energy etc) to improve the model's ability to learn trends and seasonality.

**My first attempt:**
I backshift the exogenous variables and include the same exogenous variables for every time series (i.e.: all-items time series would have same monthly unemployment information as service time series for the same date).
I concatenated the different time series into a single long DataFrame.
An snip of the test data is below (VALUE is the CPI index for the corresponding category):

[image: Test Data Example]

This unfortunate resulted in the N-HITS model creating identical forecasts for every component of inflation (all-items, energy, clothing, etc) - even for components that are drastically different from one another!

**- All_items CPI forecast:**

[image]

**- Foot wear and clothing:**

[image]

What is the appropriate way to set up exogenous data for N-HITS when using multiple time series?

Comment: Why are you back shifting the data? Did you follow their example on exogenous variables? See https://colab.research.google.com/github/Nixtla/neuralforecast/blob/main/nbs/examples/Exogenous_Variables.ipynb